# FQL does not give all the Friends likes

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to retrieve all my friends' likes using FQL. But I am not getting all the likes only those pages which have "is_community_page" value true are being returned. Here's my FQL query

```
SELECT uid, page_id FROM page_fan WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

Comment: trird your query on `https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer` and it gives the correct result.

Comment: does it give all likes of all your friends?

Comment: I am sorry. No not for all friends but there is probably a limit (there is a limit on getting status using Graph API) of the number. try getting for each friend using a loop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a max limit of 5000 results per FQL query that Facebook imposes before the results are trimmed for Privacy preferences of users. You can read this [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/) about the same.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook FQL retrieve a link to have full likes list and a samples list (quite unuseful), the point is not the limit of result, the point is fql has a different approach to list this data.

I stepped into it as well, trying to find a solution atm